# Catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX flag

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

according to the [catkin tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace) I can specify the target location of the catkin package installation using the -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX flag:

```
catkin_make install  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<path>
```

I noticed that the specified target location is only respected if some packaged have to be build first. If everything is already built, the specified location is ignored and instead the one from last successful build is used.

To make it always work you have add --force-cmake to catkin_make:

```
catkin_make --force-cmake install  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<path>
```

Maybe it would be useful to mention that in the tutorial.

Regards

- jgdo -

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199740/catkin--dcmake_install_prefix-flag/) by [jgdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1517/jgdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would actually consider this to be a bug. Any change to other CMake arguments already triggered a re-invocation of CMake. The two arguments `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` and `CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX` are handled separately due to their special semantic meaning.

I have created a pull request (https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/700) to also check for those `catkin_make` as well as `catkin_make_isolated`. With this merged and released it shouldn't require any documentation update.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1